# How to Generate Server-Side tags dynamiclly

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, code-generation

I have an ASP.net page which contains some controls.

I generate this controls by code, [Actually I have a method which uses a stringBuilder and add Serverside tag as flat string on it]

My page shows the content correctly but unfortunately my controls became like a Client-side control

For example I had a LoginView on my generated code which dosen't work, and also I had read some string from LocalResources which dosen't appear on the page

What Should I do to make my generating method correct

here is the code

```
protected string CreateSubSystem(string id, string roles, string AnonymousTemplateClass, string href, string rolesContentTemplateClass, string LoggedInTemplateClass)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<div class=\"SubSystemIconPlacement\" id=\"");
    sb.Append(id);
    sb.Append("\"><asp:LoginView runat=\"server\" ID=\"");
    sb.Append(id);
    sb.Append("\"><AnonymousTemplate><div class=\"");
    sb.Append(AnonymousTemplateClass);
    sb.Append("\"></div><asp:Label ID=\"lblDisabled");
    sb.Append(id);
    sb.Append("\" runat=\"server\" SkinID=\"OneColLabel\" meta:resourcekey=\"lbl");
    sb.Append(id);
    sb.Append("\" /></AnonymousTemplate><RoleGroups><asp:RoleGroup Roles=\"");
    sb.Append(roles);
    sb.Append("\"><ContentTemplate><a class=\"ImageLink\" href=\"");
    sb.Append(href);
    sb.Append("\"><div class=\"");
    sb.Append(rolesContentTemplateClass);
    sb.Append("\"></div></a><asp:HyperLink runat=\"server\" CssClass=\"SubSystemText\" ID=\"lnk");
    sb.Append(id);
    sb.Append(" NavigateUrl=\"~/");
    sb.Append(href);
    sb.Append(" \" meta:resourcekey=\"lbl");
    sb.Append(id);
    sb.Append("\" /></ContentTemplate></asp:RoleGroup></RoleGroups><LoggedInTemplate><div class=\"");
    sb.Append(LoggedInTemplateClass);
    sb.Append("\"></div><asp:Label runat=\"server\" SkinID=\"OneColLabel\" ID=\"lblDisabledLoggedIn");
    sb.Append(id);
    sb.Append("\" meta:resourcekey=\"lbl");
    sb.Append(id);
    sb.Append("\" /></LoggedInTemplate></asp:LoginView>");
    sb.Append("</div>");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I also use this method on page_PreRender event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate the server side control and then append them to the parent node. You cannot dump markup on client to get server side control.

As asp.net engine consumes the server controls and then render the correct client markup for you. So once on client end and free from the server side

```
Dim t As TextBox
t = New TextBox
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(t)
```

Try this [This simple expample](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Dynamic-User-Interface.aspx). Hope that helped :)